# Allow specific user accounts to launch powershell form

Tags: powershell, authentication

Question about having a specific AD user(s) launch a powershell form. Example authenticated user John.Doe would be able to run the form but his co-worker Jane.Doe would be denied. I think I am on the right track with what I found online.

```
$groupName = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] 'John.Doe'
$groupSid = $groupName.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

if ([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups -notcontains $groupSid)
{
    show 'Not Authenticated!'
}
```

Comment: Anything wrong with simply setting the ACLs on the script to allow/deny access as required?

Comment: Ansgar, I suppose that could be an option

Comment: Unless you use ACLs like Ansgar proposes, what's to stop an user to bypass the authorization check?

Comment: @vonPryz he could add the security check and sign the script so they couldn't modify it. ACLs won't block local admins on the fileserver etc.

Comment: Signing the script doesn't prevent copying its content to another (unsigned) script and running that. Even with the execution policy set to restricted they'll at least be able to copy/paste the code into a PowerShell console.

Comment: @FrodeF. If you don't trust the admin, you are up the creek without a paddle anyway.

Comment: @vonPryz usually yes, but when you have thousands of servers many people might have local admin because of their different roles. And even though you trust them and the work they normally do, you still might not want them to use or modify a script you've made. :-)